# enabling and disable of radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I have a application form in which it as radio buttons to select one of the options. I have to disable one of radio button which is not selected.
For eg if the form contains 2 subjects as Science and Commerce, and also it contains 
electives  such as computer Science and biology under Science and Mathematics and Bussiness Studies under commerce.  if my choice is Science i need to enable the electives under Science and disable the the electives under Commerce. If my choice is commerce i need to enable the electives under commerce.
Please tel me how can i do this

Here is the Code

```
$(function() {
        $("#XISubmit").click(function(){
var XISubject = XIForm.find('input[name=XISubject]:checked').val();
    if (XISubject == null || XISubject == "") {
        alert("Please select the Study Streams Offered");
        return false;
    }
   $("#XIScience").click(function(){
$(".science").attr('disabled','disabled');
$(".commerce").removeAttr('disabled');
```

});

```
document.getElementById("XIForm").submit();
    }); 

<div class="sbold sleft"><input type="radio" name='XISubject' value='Science' id="XIScience"/> Science</div>
<div class="sbold sright"><input type='radio' name='XISubject' value='Commerce' id="XICommerce"/> Commerce</div>

<div class="sleft"> English Physics Chemistry Maths</div>
<div class="sright">English Accounts Commerce Economics</div>

    <br>
    <label>37(a).If your choice of <b>Subject Stream(ques.37)</b> is Science  select one of the two electives below:</li>

            <br>

<div class="sleft"><input type='radio' name='XIElectives' value='Biology' id="XIBiology" class="science"/> Biology</div>
<div class="sright"><input type='radio' name='XIElectives' value='Computer Science' id="XICS" class="science"/> Computer Science</div>
         <br>

         <label>37(b).If your choice of <b>Subject Stream(ques.37)</b> is Commerce select one of the two electives below:
        </label>
            <br>

<div class="sleft"><input type='radio' name='XIElectives' value='Mathematics' id="XIMathematics" class="commerce"/> Mathematics</div>
<div class="sright"><input type='radio' name='XIElectives' value='Business Studies' id="XIBS" class="commerce"/>    Business Studies</div>

<br>
```

Comment: Syntax error in your line $(".science).attr('disabled', true); -- Please close the double quotes for ".science" and then try..

Answer (score 2):

Jquery will be these the easiest way to handle this.  apply `class="science"` to your science electives and `class="commerce"` to your commerce electives.

```
$("#XIScience").click(function(){
    $(".science").prop('disabled', true);
    $(".commerce").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: You probably don't have jQuery included then.

Comment: have you included the jquery library? you can use the google CDN to include it easily. put this at the top of your page. `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I used jquery too. May be I have placed the code somewhere wrongly.. Please check my code again..

Comment: you are missing closing double quotes. recopy my answer, because it made some formatting corrections.

Comment: see newest update. forgot should be using `.prop()` when dealing with properties and not `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$("#XIScience").click(function(){
    $(".science").attr('disabled','disabled');
    $(".commerce").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

**javascript:**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('science').disabled=true;
document.getElementsByClassName('commerce').disabled=false;
```

Comment: I use jquery.. Its not working for me.. May be I have placed the code somewhere wrongly..Please tel me where i need to place the code..

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use javascript, you can use the `.disabled` property and set it to false. Just grab the right elements and set it. You can use `getElementById()` to grab a specific element.

```
document.getElementById("XIScience").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("XICommerce").disabled = false;
```